# how can I take this property out of this JS object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using graphQL and gatsby to render images for a blog website I'm building but I'm having trouble taking out each image when I map out the object. I have the array of objects here but cant seem to take out fluid.src.

this is what I done so far but can't seem to go further.

```
console.log(data.allContentfulLongPost.edges.map((e) => e.node.image))
```

and I get:

```
[
    {
        "fluid": {
            "src": "//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=500&h=500&q=50",
            "srcSet": "//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=125&h=125&q=50 125w,\n//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=250&h=250&q=50 250w,\n//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=500&h=500&q=50 500w,\n//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=750&h=750&q=50 750w,\n//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=1000&h=1000&q=50 1000w,\n//images.ctfassets.net/8olws3vbib1c/5l1P6kfntYV4qnU8i26dcd/ac2321ca81df3b1db52d6a2be54f35dd/plant_protein.jpg?w=1500&h=1500&q=50 1500w"
        },
        "title": "Plant Protein Powder"
    },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
]
```

when I try

```
console.log(data.allContentfulLongPost.edges.map((e) => e.node.image.fluid.src))
```

I get "fluid is undefined"

I know only one of them has an image

Comment: use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) as `data.allContentfulLongPost?.edges?.map((e) => e.node.image.fluid.src);
`

Comment: @decpk I think your `?` are on the wrong side of the `=>` in this context but it is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the first item in the array has an image, but all of the others are null...

You can first filter them:

```
data.allContentfulLongPost.edges
  .filter(e => e.node.image)
  .map((e) => e.node.image.fluid.src)
```

This:

```
.filter(e => e.node.image)
```

Will remove all of the array values with no image (where image is `null`) in your demo output.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned  `console.log(data.allContentfulLongPost.edges.map((e) => e.node.image))` returns an array of objects.

So, In order to access "fluid" property you need to access the object first.

If you are sure you'll need only first object from an array, you can do something like this:

`console.log(data.allContentfulLongPost.edges.map((e) => e.node.image[0].fluid.src))`